# How do I replace a string that contain white space and quotes?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to replace

```
$config['module_id']['ra']  ='6'
```

with

```
$config['module_id']['ra']  ='2'
```

in a file, but isn't replaced and nothing happens.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use escape char of the bash (if you using bash) to escape `[]` I give you an example with sed:

```
sed "s@$config\['module_id'\]\['ra'\] ='6'@$config\['module_id'\]\['ra'\] ='2'@" file
```

output:

```
$config['module_id']['ra'] ='2'
```

file contain:

```
$config['module_id']['ra'] ='6'
```

Answer (score 2):

Like the [answer from AtomiX84](https://superuser.com/a/1433591/990044), just a bit shorter:

```
sed "s/\(\$config\['module_id'\]\['ra'\]\s*='\)6'/\12'/" file
```

- `s/` substitute...
- `\(` start of capturing group
- `\$config\['module_id'\]\['ra'\]` your string with escaped characters `$[]`
- `\s*='` any amount of spaces `\s*` followed by `='`
- `\)` end of capturing group
- `6'` literally `6'`
- `/\12'/` replacement by captured group `\1` and literally `2'`

To replace `6` with `2` in-place in given `file`, use option `-i''`

```
sed -i'' "s/\(\$config\['module_id'\]\['ra'\]\s*='\)6'/\12'/" file
```

To save the result to a new file, use

```
sed "s/\(\$config\['module_id'\]\['ra'\]\s*='\)6'/\12'/" file > file.new
```